# Combine 2 regions, multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am learning iterated integrals, so here is my first question.

Given these two regions

> $D_1 = \{(x, y) | 0 \le x \le 1, -2x + 3 \le y \le 3 \}$
>
> $D_2 = \{(x, y) | 1 \le x \le 5, \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2} \le y \le 3 \}$
>
> These regions are given by seperating the region bounded $y = -2x + 3, y = 3, y = \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}$ into 2 regions.

Combine this into one region $D$ such that $D = D_1 \cup D_2$.

I am confused as to how we can combine this. Can someone give me hints/ideas?

The advice given is to solve for $x$, but I don't see why that helps?

Comment: Just use$ D=D_1+D_2$. This is what I think.

Comment: Meaning there are two different regions that you integrate $D_1=A_1$ & $D_2=A_2$

Answer (score 0):

You probably see that the graph looks a bit like $|x|$ just tilted by $arctan(1) - arctan(0.5)$ degrees clockwise and moved $1$ to the right and $1$ up.

Answer (score 0):

**Draw a figure!**

Since this is an exercise in the framework of double integrals I'm giving it the following interpretation: The domain $D$ of integration is a triangle. In order to integrate over $D$ with inner integration in $y$-direction one has to split $D$ into $D_1$ and $D_2$, as indicated. One then obtains
$$\eqalign{\int_Df(x,y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)&=\int_{D_1}f(x,y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)+\int_{D_2}f(x,y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)\cr
&=\int_0^1\int_{3-2x}^3f(x,y)\>dy\>dx+\int_1^5\int_{(x+1)/2}^3 f(x,y)\>dy\>dx\ .\cr}$$
Now one side of $D$ is horizontal. This makes it possible to compute the double integral in one stroke by taking the inner integral in $x$-direction: 
$$\int_Df(x,y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\int_1^3\int_{(3-y)/2}^{2y-1}f(x,y)\>dx\>dy\ .$$
In order to find the boundaries of the inner integral we computed the minimal and the maximal occurring $x$ for a given $y$.